# image.tag (in values.yaml) vs. appVersion (in Chart.yaml)

Tags: kubernetes-helm

When creating a new Helm chart via `helm create chart`, Helm will create an `appVersion` field in `Chart.yaml` and an `image.tag` field in `values.yaml`.

For debugging purposes, it's convenient to set `image.tag` on deployment instead of having to create a new chart. Otherwise, however, I keep them in sync because I want to see the true version of the Docker image when looking at the output of `helm list`.

Despite for debugging, is there a reason to use `{{ .Values.image.tag }}` instead of `{{ .Chart.AppVersion }}` in the deployment file?

Comment: same question, which should be updated and why? it is very ambigous, there are 3 versions all over the place: chart.version, chart.appVersion and values.item.tag, there are no clear information about them in the documentation

Answer (score 24):

If for your version control needs they are the same, then it doesn't matter.

Some even [recommend](https://jfrog.com/blog/helm-charts-best-practices/) as best practice to use

```
image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ default .Chart.AppVersion .Values.image.tag }}"
```

However consider often `{{ .Values.image.tag }}` and `{{ .Chart.AppVersion }}` may use different version.

`{{ .Values.image.tag }}` - Docker image tag.

`{{ .Chart.AppVersion }}` - Version of the app that is inside the image - you may be developing an app that you version control separately from your image.

`{{ .Chart.version }}` - If you are developing the Chart you need to version control it. Each change to the template should result version increase. [Helm documentation](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/) says:

> Every chart must have a version number. A version must follow the SemVer 2 standard. Unlike Helm Classic, Kubernetes Helm uses version numbers as release markers. Packages in repositories are identified by name plus version.

Comment: Please remark that this check will fail if you don't have a key "image:" in your values.yaml file, which can be fixed by simply adding an empty one as follows: "image: {}".